# How to merge repeating xml elements in a single xml element based on unique a field using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, tibco

I have a scenario in which I need to merge the XML elements in a single root element based on unique field.

Request:

```
     <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<ns0:klanten xmlns:ns0 = "http://integratie.com/typen/klant/klantmvs/1.0">
    <ns0:klant xmlns:ns0 = "http://integratie.com/typen/klant/klantmvs/1.0">
        <ns0:klantId MVS = "36301586">36301586</ns0:klantId>
        <ns0:accounts>
            <ns0:account>
                <ns0:accountVolgnummer>3</ns0:accountVolgnummer>
                <ns0:betaalwijze>AGI</ns0:betaalwijze>
                <ns0:classificatie>B2C</ns0:classificatie>
                <ns0:gewensteNotaMedium>VZD</ns0:gewensteNotaMedium>
                <ns0:bankrekening>
                    <ns0:bankrekeningnummer>BNGH0285108743</ns0:bankrekeningnummer>
                    <ns0:bankrekeninghouder/>
                    <ns0:bankrekeningland/>
                    <ns0:financieleInstelling/>
                    <ns0:standaardrekeningIndicator>true</ns0:standaardrekeningIndicator>
                </ns0:bankrekening>
                <ns0:startdatum>2014-06-05</ns0:startdatum>
                <ns0:einddatum>2014-07-25</ns0:einddatum>
                </ns0:account>
        </ns0:accounts>
    </ns0:klant>
    <ns0:klant xmlns:ns0 = "http://integratie.com/typen/klant/klantmvs/1.0">
        <ns0:klantId MVS = "36301586">36301586</ns0:klantId>
        <ns0:accounts>
            <ns0:account>
                <ns0:accountVolgnummer>464</ns0:accountVolgnummer>
                <ns0:betaalwijze>AGI</ns0:betaalwijze>
                <ns0:classificatie>B2C</ns0:classificatie>
                <ns0:gewensteNotaMedium>VZD</ns0:gewensteNotaMedium>
                <ns0:bankrekening>
                    <ns0:bankrekeningnummer>BNGH0285108743</ns0:bankrekeningnummer>
                    <ns0:bankrekeninghouder/>
                    <ns0:bankrekeningland/>
                    <ns0:financieleInstelling/>
                    <ns0:standaardrekeningIndicator>true</ns0:standaardrekeningIndicator>
                </ns0:bankrekening>
                <ns0:startdatum>2014-12-12</ns0:startdatum>
                <ns0:einddatum>2015-03-09</ns0:einddatum>           
            </ns0:account>
        </ns0:accounts>
    </ns0:klant>
</ns0:klanten>
```

Desired OutPut:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<ns0:klanten xmlns:ns0 = "http://integratie.com/typen/klant/klantmvs/1.0">
<ns0:klant xmlns:ns0 = "http://integratie.com/typen/klant/klantmvs/1.0">
        <ns0:klantId MVS = "36301586">36301586</ns0:klantId>
        <ns0:accounts>
            <ns0:account>
                <ns0:accountVolgnummer>464</ns0:accountVolgnummer>
                <ns0:betaalwijze>AGI</ns0:betaalwijze>
                <ns0:classificatie>B2C</ns0:classificatie>
                <ns0:gewensteNotaMedium>VZD</ns0:gewensteNotaMedium>
                <ns0:bankrekening>
                    <ns0:bankrekeningnummer>BNGH0285108743</ns0:bankrekeningnummer>
                    <ns0:bankrekeninghouder/>
                    <ns0:bankrekeningland/>
                    <ns0:financieleInstelling/>
                    <ns0:standaardrekeningIndicator>true</ns0:standaardrekeningIndicator>
                </ns0:bankrekening>
                <ns0:startdatum>2014-12-12</ns0:startdatum>
                <ns0:einddatum>2015-03-09</ns0:einddatum>
            </ns0:account>
            <ns0:account>
                <ns0:accountVolgnummer>3</ns0:accountVolgnummer>
                <ns0:betaalwijze>AGI</ns0:betaalwijze>
                <ns0:classificatie>B2C</ns0:classificatie>
                <ns0:gewensteNotaMedium>VZD</ns0:gewensteNotaMedium>
                <ns0:bankrekening>
                    <ns0:bankrekeningnummer>BNGH0285108743</ns0:bankrekeningnummer>
                    <ns0:bankrekeninghouder/>
                    <ns0:bankrekeningland/>
                    <ns0:financieleInstelling/>
                    <ns0:standaardrekeningIndicator>true</ns0:standaardrekeningIndicator>
                </ns0:bankrekening>
                <ns0:startdatum>2014-06-05</ns0:startdatum>
                <ns0:einddatum>2014-07-25</ns0:einddatum>
                </ns0:account>
        </ns0:accounts>
    </ns0:klant>
</ns0:klanten>
```

I am trying to implement this in tibco but didn't succeed. Can anyone help me to write xslt for it?

Comment: Hi, I'm curious. As I'm learning XSLT at the moment I'd like to ask, if my answer could solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this: Use a key to get distinct IDs and use these distinct IDs to traverse the `klantId` nodes. Pick their account data.

I'm sure there are people around who could solve this with half of the lines, but it seems to prepare what you need:

Tested here: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.VlzGqNgveUl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://integratie.com/typen/klant/klantmvs/1.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

    <xsl:key name="IDs" match="/ns0:klanten/ns0:klant/ns0:klantId" use="@MVS" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns0:klanten>
            <xsl:for-each select="//ns0:klantId[generate-id()=generate-id(key('IDs',.)[1])]">
                <xsl:variable name="currentId" select="." />
                <ns0:klant>
                    <ns0:klantid mvs="{$currentId}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$currentId" />
                    </ns0:klantid>
                    <ns0:accounts>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//ns0:klantId[@MVS=$currentId]">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="../ns0:accounts/ns0:account" />
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ns0:accounts>
                </ns0:klant>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns0:klanten>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your solution works but I have manged to done it in Tibco BW. :)